# jQuery scripts execution order and optimization

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In order to cleanup the DOM by some dynamically generated empty divs, I have written the following jQuery scripts, basically I have divs containing empty span and br and div containing nothing, they all need to vanish. By executing them from the console in the following order I have found that they will perfectly clean my document without leaving a single empty div.

```
$('.release--content div span:empty').remove();

$('.release--content div br:empty').remove();

$('.release--content div:empty').remove();
```

Is there a way to avoid to run multiple separated scripts by writing a single script? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only group the first two selectors into one, since the last one depends on the first two `.remove()`

```js
$('.release--content div span:empty, .release--content div br:empty').remove();

$('.release--content div:empty').remove(); // the divs are only empty if the first line is run
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all with a single selector:

```
$('.release--content div span:empty, .release--content div br:empty, .release--content div:empty').remove();
```

Or, perhaps easier to read:

```
$('
  .release--content div span:empty,
  .release--content div br:empty,
  .release--content div:empty
').remove();
```

Comment: I have just tried and the empty divs are not being deleted from the DOM, just the ones containing empty br and span. I need to run the script again to make them vanish.

Comment: Try `$('.release--content div span:empty,.release--content div br:empty').parent().remove()` to remove the parent divs of the empty `<span>` and `<br>` tags.